# how to show a win form of my C# app in client PC

Tags: client, detect

I have a **win app** on my server that is supposed to display a **set of specific** pictures and videos for **each client** . I have no idea how to detect clients and displaying appropriate slides for each one .

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about client server application here try to socket programming which provide you the functionalities of Ip Addresses then you can get the ip address of a client then do what ever you want to do

Comment: i just make a code of client server Application but on a single Pc If you need that i can give may be it helps you a lot b/c on that code you just have to garb client Ip thats all.how can i give you code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two different project to run this Application First make a project which should be called Client and Copy paste this Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Task4Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data;
            string input;
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                server.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable To Connect To Server");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(server);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
          ///  data = streamReader.ReadLine();
          //  Console.WriteLine(data);
            while (true)
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "exit")
                {
                    break;
                }
                streamWriter.WriteLine(input);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                data = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(data);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting From Server");
            streamWriter.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            networkStream.Close();
            server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            server.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then make a project which should be called Server and copy paste this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;



namespace Task4Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data;
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            Socket newSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            newSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            newSocket.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("waiting for a clinet ...");
            Socket client = newSocket.Accept();
            IPEndPoint newClient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", newClient.Address, newClient.Port);
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(client);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
           // string welcome = "Welcome to my Haseeb Server";
           // streamWriter.WriteLine(welcome);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    data = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {

                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", newClient.Address);
            streamWriter.Close();
            streamReader.Close();
            networkStream.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

then first run the Server Application Then Client and Sent message from Client to server it will behave like Client Server Application enjoy